# Efficient sub-string search over large dataset

Tags: r, regex, optimization, substring, grepl

I have a large dataset `tPro1` (~500k points).  Seen below, the variable of interest is `tPro1$Path`.

```
      Path                                  Row      rm                                              
1  >root>aaaa>bbbb>cccc>dddd>hello         1        TRUE
2  >root>aaaa>bbbb>cccc>dddd>greetings     2        TRUE
3  >root>aaaa>bbbb>cccc>dddd>example       3        TRUE
4  >root>iiii>jjjj>kkkk>llll>mmmm          4        TRUE
5  >root>iiii>jjjj>kkkk>nnnn>testing       5        TRUE
```

I also have a smaller dataset, let's call it `Sub1`, of a couple dozen or so dataponts.  It has higher level paths than `tPro1`.

```
     [1] ">root>aaaa>bbbb>cccc>dddd"
     [2] ">root>aaaa>bbbb>eeee>ffff"
     [3] ">root>aaaa>bbbb>gggg>hhhh" 
     [4] ">root>iiii>jjjj>kkkk>llll>mmmm"
     [5] ">root>iiii>jjjj>kkkk>nnnn" 
     [6] ">root>oooo>pppp>qqqq"
```

What I am trying to do is associate the longer paths in `tPro1` with the shorter ones in `Sub1`. `tPro1` is a copy of some key info from `Pro0`.  Output `Pro0` would be

```
          Path                                  Short_path                                                    
1  >root>aaaa>bbbb>cccc>dddd>hello         >root>aaaa>bbbb>cccc>dddd
2  >root>aaaa>bbbb>cccc>dddd>greetings     >root>aaaa>bbbb>cccc>dddd
3  >root>aaaa>bbbb>cccc>dddd>example       >root>aaaa>bbbb>cccc>dddd
4  >root>iiii>jjjj>kkkk>llll>mmmm          >root>iiii>jjjj>kkkk>llll>mmmm
5  >root>iiii>jjjj>kkkk>nnnn>testing       >root>iiii>jjjj>kkkk>nnnn
```

I've written a loop that for each path in `Sub1`, grepl's each `tPro1` to see if it is a substring.  For 500k*24 points, this would be a very inefficient process, so I've tried some optimizations:

1. Note `tPro1$rm`.  When a substring is found, this is set to false.  They are removed/skipped afterwards to save pointless recheck time.

   2. A Path s may appear multiple times in `tPro1`.  Thus when a valid substring p is found for s, instead of continuing to grepl, the algorithm goes through the dataset and looks for all unchecked instances of s.

My code is

```
start.time <- Sys.time()

for (p in Sub1$Path) {
  for (i in 1:NROW(tPro1)) {
    if (tPro1[i,3]) {
      if (grepl(p, tPro1[i,1], fixed=TRUE)) {
        # Replace all of subpath 
        for (j in i:NROW(tPro1)) {
          if (tPro1[j,1] == tPro1[i,1]) {
            Pro0[tPro1[j,2],2] <- p
            tPro1[j,3] <- FALSE
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  v <- unlist(tPro1[,3])
  tPro1 <- tPro1[v,]
}

end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <- end.time - start.time
time.taken
```

Processing the full dataset does not halt in human time (on my machine at least).  For illustrative purposes, doing batches of 1000 at a time (reduced `tPro1`) takes 46secs. 2000 takes 1 mins, 3000:1.4mins.

Any glaring improvements that could be made, or is it just the nature of the problem?

EDIT: There are around 54k unique long paths, and also not all of the long paths have a corresponding short path (eg in `tPro1` there is `>root>strange>path`, whereas in `sub1` there is no path of the form `>root>strange`)

EDIT2: Following [rosscova](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4731848/rosscova)'s answer below, the time was taken down from possibly eternity, to 279.75 seconds!

Comment: can you send some data as well (like a link or smth?)

Comment: Does the string `>root>aaaa>bbbb>cccc>dddd>hello` always the same number of `>`. I mean can you have eg? `>root>aaaa>bbbb>cccc>dddd>xxxx>ΖΖΖΖΖ>hello`

Comment: unfortunately the data I'm working with can't be disclosed, which makes things awkward for reproducibility I know.  The strings have a variable number of >'s

Comment: Cool! So let me know one thing. all you need to know if the BIG table contains string of the small one, right?

Comment: Aye, looking to see if a string in the big table contains a string in the small one (and associates the two)

Comment: Ok, no need to loop. I am posting an example, and we can work things out

Comment: Excellent, I'm curious to see what you have in mind

Comment: Yeah I don't see the use for a loop either... cast it to a data.table.. and use something like DT[,shortPath := gsub("(^.*>)","\\1",Path)]. Then check if this shortPath occurs in your shortpath table... hence merge it with that one

Comment: @zwep, I'm under the impression there may be more than one ">" added onto the `shortpath`. Your method would compare everything up to the last ">", which may not be appropriate. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @PrunusPersica I implemented the changes in my extensive answer. Let me know if there is something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that `sub` is so small could help a lot in reducing the number of iterations necessary. Here's a more efficient way than what you've got, although I'm still using a loop here.

First, set up some test data. Use the same sizes as you've specified:

```
set.seed(123)

sub <- sapply( seq_len( 24 ), function(x) {
    paste( sample( c( letters, ">" ),
                   12,
                   replace = TRUE,
                   prob = c( rep( 1, 26 ), 8 ) ),
           collapse = "")
} )
head( sub, 3 )
# [1] "puhyz>lymjbj" "rn>yc>fbyrda" "qsmop>byrv>k"
```

Use `sub` to create `tPro1` such that there are substrings to find as appropriate.

```
tPro1 <- paste0( sample( sub,
                         5E5,
                         replace = TRUE ),
                 sample( c( ">hello", ">adf", ">;kjadf" ),
                         5E5,
                         replace = TRUE )
)
head( tPro1, 3 )
# [1] "bjwhrj>j>>zj>adf"   "b>>>zpx>fpvg>hello" ">q>hn>ljsllh>adf"
```

Now use a while loop. Iterate over `sub`, getting as many matches as possible in each iteration. Stop iterating if we get to the end of `sub`, or if all values have been filled.

```
results <- vector( "character", length( tPro1 ) )
i <- 1L
system.time(
    while( sum( results == "" ) > 0L && i <= length( sub ) ) {
        results[ grep( sub[i], tPro1 ) ] <- sub[i]
        i <- i + 1L
    }
)
#    user  system elapsed 
#  4.655   0.007   4.661
```

Output the results.

```
output <- data.frame( tPro1 = tPro1, results = results, stringsAsFactors = FALSE )
head( output, 3 )

#                             tPro1                  results
# 1 >>ll>ldsjbzzcszcniwm>>em>;kjadf >>ll>ldsjbzzcszcniwm>>em
# 2 ijka>ca>>>ddpmhilphqlt>c>;kjadf ijka>ca>>>ddpmhilphqlt>c
# 3 zpnsniwyletn>qzifzjtrjg>>;kjadf zpnsniwyletn>qzifzjtrjg>
```

So this is not a completely vectorised solution, but it does save you some time. We're down to 4.6s for the same sized dataset that you're working with.

EDIT: Silly me, I was working with `sub` a few thousand values long. After reducing the size of `sub` to a couple of dozen like you say, it makes this a lot quicker!

EDIT: with the data as you've shown it, you may need to create the `tPro1` and `sub` vectors first:

```
tPro1.vec <- tPro1$Path
sub <- Sub1$Path

results <- vector( "character", length( tPro1.vec ) )
i <- 1L
while( sum( results == "" ) > 0L && i <= length( sub ) ) {
    results[ grep( sub[i], tPro1.vec ) ] <- sub[i]
    i <- i + 1L
}
```

Comment: Exploring this answer, though so far my results vector is being returned as empty.  Will append any further progress though.  With `grep( sub[i], tPro1 )`, this returns a vector of all the rows in `tPro1` for which `sub[i]` is a substring?  Seems like it executes much quicker than I'd expect

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You should feed in `sub` and `tPro1` as vectors here, so with your data, it may be necessary to have them as `tPro1$Path` and `Sub1$Path`.

Comment: I've added an edit, which might help. I'm just creating the vectors from your data before starting the loop, to make sure they're structured correctly for the analysis.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, cheers!  My running time was 279.75 seconds. 
 My original method was 500k*24 iterations, but since I pruned it should be less in actuality.  This way always runs through 24*500k iterations(?) but is more efficient because it uses more efficient operations each iteration?

Answer (score 2):

Using fuzzy-matching, `agrepl`:

```
tPro1$Short_path <- Sub1$Path[ apply(sapply(Sub1$Path, function(i) agrepl(i, tPro1$Path)), 1, which) ] 

tPro1

#                                  Path Row   rm                     Short_path
# 1     >root>aaaa>bbbb>cccc>dddd>hello   1 TRUE      >root>aaaa>bbbb>cccc>dddd
# 2 >root>aaaa>bbbb>cccc>dddd>greetings   2 TRUE      >root>aaaa>bbbb>cccc>dddd
# 3   >root>aaaa>bbbb>cccc>dddd>example   3 TRUE      >root>aaaa>bbbb>cccc>dddd
# 4      >root>iiii>jjjj>kkkk>llll>mmmm   4 TRUE >root>iiii>jjjj>kkkk>llll>mmmm
# 5   >root>iiii>jjjj>kkkk>nnnn>testing   5 TRUE      >root>iiii>jjjj>kkkk>nnnn
```

## data

```
tPro1  <- read.table(text = "Path                                  Row      rm                                              
1  >root>aaaa>bbbb>cccc>dddd>hello         1        TRUE
2  >root>aaaa>bbbb>cccc>dddd>greetings     2        TRUE
3  >root>aaaa>bbbb>cccc>dddd>example       3        TRUE
4  >root>iiii>jjjj>kkkk>llll>mmmm          4        TRUE
5  >root>iiii>jjjj>kkkk>nnnn>testing       5        TRUE",
                     header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


Sub1 <- data.frame(Path = c(">root>aaaa>bbbb>cccc>dddd",
                            ">root>aaaa>bbbb>eeee>ffff",
                            ">root>aaaa>bbbb>gggg>hhhh",
                            ">root>iiii>jjjj>kkkk>llll>mmmm",
                            ">root>iiii>jjjj>kkkk>nnnn",
                            ">root>oooo>pppp>qqqq"),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: My implementation of this is alas took an hour before throwing an error*.  I'm still having a little trouble understanding the process in your function: sapply goes through each subpath, and uses agrepl to the entire `tPro1` set.  This returns for each subpath, a vector of indexes in `tPro1` which are valid paths.  apply then does something with these vectors

Comment: *`Error in `[.default`(xj, i) : invalid subscript type 'list'`.  Still investigating

Comment: @PrunusPersica error probably because my solution is tested using dataframes, we need to update to match with data.tables. Regarding double apply, break it down to see what each one is doing. If still not clear, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Given the two datasets (in the form of `data.table`):

```
library(data.table) # for data manipulation
library(stringi) # for string manipulation

 >dt1 
                               Path Row   rm
 1:     >root>aaaa>bbbb>cccc>dddd>hello   1 TRUE
 2: >root>aaaa>bbbb>cccc>dddd>greetings   2 TRUE
 3:   >root>aaaa>bbbb>cccc>dddd>example   3 TRUE
 4:      >root>iiii>jjjj>kkkk>llll>mmmm   4 TRUE
 5:   >root>iiii>jjjj>kkkk>nnnn>testing   5 TRUE

 > dt2 # introduced column name `names`

                        names
 1:      >root>aaaa>bbbb>cccc>dddd
 2:      >root>aaaa>bbbb>eeee>ffff
 3:      >root>aaaa>bbbb>gggg>hhhh
 4: >root>iiii>jjjj>kkkk>llll>mmmm
 5:      >root>iiii>jjjj>kkkk>nnnn
 6:           >root>oooo>pppp>qqqq

dt1b<-cbind(t(dt1[,stri_split(Path,fixed=">")]),dt1[,.(Row,rm)])[,V1:=NULL]
dt2b<-data.table(t(dt2[,stri_split(str = names,fixed=">")]))[,V1:=NULL]

 >dt1b
      V2   V3   V4   V5   V6        V7 Row   rm
1: root aaaa bbbb cccc dddd     hello   1 TRUE
2: root aaaa bbbb cccc dddd greetings   2 TRUE
3: root aaaa bbbb cccc dddd   example   3 TRUE
4: root iiii jjjj kkkk llll      mmmm   4 TRUE
5: root iiii jjjj kkkk nnnn   testing   5 TRUE
```

and

```
 >dt2b
      V2   V3   V4   V5   V6   V7
1: root aaaa bbbb cccc dddd      
2: root aaaa bbbb eeee ffff     
3: root aaaa bbbb gggg hhhh     
4: root iiii jjjj kkkk llll mmmm
5: root iiii jjjj kkkk nnnn     
6: root oooo pppp qqqq      root
```

Finally I compare each row of the `dt1b` with every row of `dt2b` via:

```
  sub1<-subset(dt1b, select = grep("^V+", names(dt1b),perl = TRUE,value = TRUE))
```

## Create (list that contains) all the possible comparisons

```
  l1<-lapply(seq(1:nrow(sub1)),function(x) {l1<-lapply(seq(1:nrow(dt2b)),function(y) {l2<-data.table(t(sub1[x] %in% dt2b[y]));names(l2)<-paste0(dt2b[y]);return(l2)}); names(l1)<-paste(sub1[x],collapse=" ");return(l1)})
```

portion of result

```
     l1[1:2]
    [[1]]
    [[1]]$`root aaaa bbbb cccc dddd hello`
       root aaaa bbbb cccc dddd      
    1: TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE

    [[1]]$<NA>
       root aaaa bbbb  eeee  ffff      
    1: TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

    [[1]]$<NA>
       root aaaa bbbb  gggg  hhhh      
    1: TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

    [[1]]$<NA>
       root  iiii  jjjj  kkkk  llll  mmmm
    1: TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

    [[1]]$<NA>
       root  iiii  jjjj  kkkk  nnnn      
    1: TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

    [[1]]$<NA>
       root  oooo  pppp  qqqq        root
    1: TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE



    [[2]]
    [[2]]$`root aaaa bbbb cccc dddd greetings`
       root aaaa bbbb cccc dddd      
    1: TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE

    [[2]]$<NA>
       root aaaa bbbb  eeee  ffff      
    1: TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

    [[2]]$<NA>
       root aaaa bbbb  gggg  hhhh      
    1: TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

    [[2]]$<NA>
       root  iiii  jjjj  kkkk  llll  mmmm
    1: TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

    [[2]]$<NA>
       root  iiii  jjjj  kkkk  nnnn      
    1: TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

    [[2]]$<NA>
       root  oooo  pppp  qqqq        root
    1: TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

So now you can have a *score* per row of dt1b e.g. 0/6 (not even close),..., 5/6 (almost identical), 6/6 (exactly identical).

## IDEA (edit)

Here is my idea:

```
l2<-lapply(seq_along(1:length(l1)),function(x) {
  z=rbindlist(t(l1[[x]][1:nrow(dt2b)]),fill = TRUE)
  z=cbind(z,score=apply(z,1,sum,na.rm=TRUE))
  setorder(z,-score)
  z[,V1:=NULL]
  z<-cbind(t(rep(names(l1[[x]][1]))),z)
  names(z)[1]<-"initialString"
  return(z)
})


   > l2[1:2]
 [[1]]
                     initialString root aaaa bbbb cccc dddd  eeee  ffff  gggg  hhhh  iiii  jjjj  kkkk  llll  mmmm  nnnn score
 1: root aaaa bbbb cccc dddd hello TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     5
 2: root aaaa bbbb cccc dddd hello TRUE TRUE TRUE   NA   NA FALSE FALSE    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     3
 3: root aaaa bbbb cccc dddd hello TRUE TRUE TRUE   NA   NA    NA    NA FALSE FALSE    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     3
 4: root aaaa bbbb cccc dddd hello TRUE   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA     1
 5: root aaaa bbbb cccc dddd hello TRUE   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA    NA FALSE     1

 [[2]]
                         initialString root aaaa bbbb cccc dddd  eeee  ffff  gggg  hhhh  iiii  jjjj  kkkk  llll  mmmm  nnnn score
 1: root aaaa bbbb cccc dddd greetings TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     5
 2: root aaaa bbbb cccc dddd greetings TRUE TRUE TRUE   NA   NA FALSE FALSE    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     3
 3: root aaaa bbbb cccc dddd greetings TRUE TRUE TRUE   NA   NA    NA    NA FALSE FALSE    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     3
 4: root aaaa bbbb cccc dddd greetings TRUE   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA     1
 5: root aaaa bbbb cccc dddd greetings TRUE   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA    NA FALSE     1
```

... or by keeping the row with maximum `score` column, (this can be attained via: `return(z)` changes into `return(z[score==max(score)])` in the `l2 lapply()` above) and `rbindlist(t(l2[1:length(l2)]))`:

```
                        initialString root aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh iiii jjjj kkkk llll mmmm nnnn score
1:     root aaaa bbbb cccc dddd hello TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA     5
2: root aaaa bbbb cccc dddd greetings TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA     5
3:   root aaaa bbbb cccc dddd example TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA     5
4:      root iiii jjjj kkkk llll mmmm TRUE   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE   NA     6
5:   root iiii jjjj kkkk nnnn testing TRUE   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA TRUE TRUE TRUE   NA   NA TRUE     5
```

The column `initialString` now holds the initial string. The following columns hold its decomposition into substrings and its *similarity* score

Comment: `lapply` is really a loop, even though it looks different to `for` or `while`.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should solve your problem in no time.

```
library(data.table)
library(stringi)

Pro0 <- data.table(tPro1)

for (i in 1:length(Sub1$Short_path)) {
  Pro0[stri_detect_fixed(Path, Sub1$Short_path[i]), Short_path:=Sub1$Short_path[i]]
}
```

Using this approach I just associated 230k path names with 14 shorter path names within a second.

And this is the code I used to create the datasets tPro1 and Sub1 corresponding to your ones:

```
tPro1 <- data.table('Path' = list.files(path = '/usr', full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE))
Sub1 <- data.table('Short_path' = list.files(path = '/usr', full.names = TRUE))
```